# Ionic 2 open modal on platform resume

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I am currently working on an Ionic 2 app which requires authentication each time the app moves into the background and resumes.

```js
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'item-details',
  templateUrl: 'item-details.html'
})
export class ItemDetailsPage {
   private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginModalPage, true);
      modal.present();
  });
}
```

The issue I am having is that when the app resumes, it is correctly detects that it has resumed but then gives the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Attempted to assign to readonly property
```

When I use web inspector attached to the simulator it seems to imply the modal is undefined but I am unsure why.

Comment: can you show LoginModalPage class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you have created `modal`

`let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginModalPage, true);`

But from docs, instance is created with  `create(component, data, opts)` where `data` is an `object`. In your case it is a `boolean`. So you need to pass an `object`.  Here is the [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

Comment: That makes a whole tonne of sense. I will try it later and mark as correct if it works. Thanks!